# When is a subset is homotopy type of a regular covering?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ are finite CW complexes such that $X\subsetneq Y$ such that $X$ is not homotopy equivalent to $Y$. Can $X$ be homotopy type of a finite regular covering of $Y$? If Yes can we have an example? Can we put some condition on $X$ for which a subset cannot be a regular covering?Is it possible that $\pi_1(X)$ is finite but $\pi_1(Y)$ is not?

Comment: $Y$ seems to play no role in your question. Is there a typo?

Comment: Yes@RobArthan I have edited now.

Comment: If you are using "regular" in the sense defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Deck_(covering)_transformation_group,_regular_covers), then you can take $X = Y = S^1$ and then every finite covering of $Y$ has a total space that is homeomorphic to $X$.

Comment: Dear @RobArthan I actually wanted proper subset. I have edited.

Comment: If you want a proper subcomplex, take $X=S^1$ and $Y$ obtained by attaching a 1-cell along one of its boundary points to $X$. Then $X$ is again homotopy-equivalent to $Y$. If you want some conditions, assume that $Y$ is aspherical but $X\subset Y$ is not.

Comment: If you take $X = [0, 1/2] \times S^1$ and $Y = [0, 1] \times S^1$, you get that $X$ is a proper subset of $Y$, but any finite covering of $Y$ is homeomorphic to $X$.

Comment: I think, you should assume that the inclusion $X\to Y$ is not a homotopy-equivalence. Then it becomes an interesting question.

Comment: Thanks @RobArthan for your comments.

Comment: Dear @MoisheKohan yes you are right about homotopy equivalence. Thanks for your insightful comments.

Comment: You should edit your question then again.

Comment: @MoisheKohan. Your suggestion does add some interest, but if you think about $X = [0, 1] \times S^1$ as an annulus in the plane, you can embed it in $[0, 1]  \times [0, 1]$ and then embed the latter in $Y = X$. The composite embedding is not a homotopy equivalence, but $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic. I think the assumption should be that $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: @RobArthan: Right, except, it should be "not homotopy-equivalent."

Comment: @MoisheKohan: I guess either option is up for grabs: "not homotopy equivalent" is a stronger assumption than "not homeomorphic", so I was proposing the weaker assumption that bars the counter-examples listed so far.

Comment: A "non-homeomorphic" example, I already gave, see above.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: take $Y$ to be $[0, 1] \times W_n$ where $W_n$ is a wedge of $n$ circles ($n > 1$). The proper finite covers of $W_n$ are planar graphs that are not homotopy-equivalent to $W_n$ or to $Y$ , and you can embed any one of them you choose, say $X$. in a the interior of a $2$ cell in a CW structure on $Y$, to get an example where $X$ has the homotopy type of a finite cover of $Y$ but is not homotopy-equivalent to $Y$.

Comment: I feel like I am missing something, but isn't this easy to achieve using the mapping cylinder?   E.g., take $X=S^2$ and take $Y$ to be the mapping cylinder of the covering $X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$.